# Java how can I pass array values from one method to another

Tags: java, arrays, methods

As the title of the question suggests, I would like to know how to share array values between methods. My main objective is this. I have a method where the user inputs are stored in an array and then this method will basically check the user input values (validation process)
say something like this
(please ignore the syntax)

```
public void validation()
{
 String[] accnumbers = new String[20];
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter the account number:");
    accno = sc.nextLine(); 

int j;
      for (j = 0; j < accnumber.length; j++)
      if (accnumber[j] == null) break;
      if (j==accnumber.length)  
      {
            System.out.print("limited.");
      } 
      else
      { 
          accnumber[j]=accno;               
      }

}
```

//so that is for the vaidation part and as you can see that there is a accnumbers array now i want to share that in the following method, which basically searches for a accnumber that is valid in the string

```
public void search(String[] acnumbAry,BigDecimal[] acbalanceArray,String accnumbinput)
{
 if(Arrays.asList(acnumbAry).contains(accnumbinput))
       {
           System.out.println("The value is contained");
       }
       else
       {
           System.out.println("The value is not contained");
       }

}
```

// but in the Main method I have a display menu that gives the user an option to either validate or search, so when the user chooses to search then I am not sure how to get the array values(if any) from the validate method.

Comment: Please don't destroy your own posts. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148021/valid-question-deleted-because-of-invalid-edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use arrays!!! Java ain't C!

Unless you are coding some low-level code that needs to be super fast, use the Collections API. If this is homework (I suspect it is) and your professor has told you to use arrays, demand that the Dean of the faculty to remove him immediately from teaching before he does any more damage! Arrays are a terrible choice for nearly all situations.

In this case, use a `List`, which grows in size automatically. No need to check for size etc. Then return the List from your method. Your code will shrink to this:

```
public List<String> validation() {
    List<String> accnumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter account numbers (blank to finish):");
    while (true) {
        String accno = sc.nextLine(); 
        if (accno.equals("")) { // blank ends input
            return accnumbers;
        }
        accnumbers.add(accno); // will take any number of account numbers
    }
}
```

You don't even need your `search` method, just use `list.contains()` in line.

Comment: haha, i would certainly pass along the message to my Dean. But yes u suspected right this is an assignment and I must use arrays so trying to make the best of it. But i guess this is for us to learn the programming basics..In general

Comment: Arrays are rarely used in java programming, and never used at the "business" level (only when manipulating byte streams etc). I would give a "fail" when reviewing any code that used arrays and make the programmer replace them with collections. If he wants to teach you to about arrays, then set a problem that might use them in real life - perhaps to hold positions of pieces of a checkers game. It is simply "wrong" to use an array here and will only produce bad code. You teacher isn't very smart and clearly has no commercial experience.

Answer (score 0):

I would have rather dropped `String[] acnumbAry` in member list of the class and have initialized it with a constructor.

Copying the array during function calls will only hamper the performance.

Answer (score 0):

You could return the array in your method:

```
public String[] validation()
{
  String[] accnumbers = new String[20];

  // your validation code

  return accnumbers;
}
```

Let me, however, suggest you some changes to your code:

- You could populate the array before validating it, and then passing it to your `validation` method. I'd too suggest you to call it `validate` rather: `bool validate(String[] values)`. It would feel more intuitive to me, because validating and receiving data are generally two different things. As *Anon* writes, you could store the `accnumbers` in an instance field.
- As you are working with `contains` in your sample, you might be better of using a `Set` instead of an array or `List`, since searching sets in generally quicker.

Comment: but then i dont think i can call non static methods in the static method and my Main method is a static

Comment: You could also make all the stuff static (all methods, and the field you use). I'd recommend you to work in an instance you create in `main` though.

Comment: so u mean to say ur suggested method public static String[] validation()?

Comment: Well it is not static yet. How do you invoke the method now?